# freeglut failed to open display, when running binary from Windows of a fractal algorithm. Help maybe?

Tags: windows, bash, freeglut

So I am trying to program some fractal algorithms, it's a PPM Interactive one, after several problems with freeglut and the packages I get the "freeglut (./a.out): failed to open display '0.0'" when running the binary file of the program. I am compiling from Bash On Ubuntu on Windows, and maybe are some packages that I am missing?Also if I do "cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep X" the result is X11Forwarding yes..and X11DisplayOffset 10. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance guys :).